# How to take screenshot of GLSurfaceView programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to take the screenshot of GlSurfaceView programmatically in android. I am using the below code to achieve this functionality but I could not achieve this functionality. Please help me to take screenshot of GLSurfaceVIew programmatically.

Caling method.

```
createBitmapFromGLSurface((int)customglSurfaceView.getX(), (int)customglSurfaceView.getY(),
```

Method Body

```
public static Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h) throws OutOfMemoryError {
    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try {
        glObject.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try the solution here: [StackOverflow: OpenGL screenshot Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632485/screenshot-in-android